# Open an Excel file as Read Only using os.startfile() with Python

Tags: python, excel

I made a tool for my colleagues to open Excel files we often use. Sometimes a colleague only needs to open it as Read Only. If I use os.startfile() and nobody else has opened the file, you will open the file as Writeable but the next person will only be able to open the file as Read Only. I want them to have an option to open the file as Read Only, no matter if it is already opend or not. I know Excel has an option to open a file as read only. Maybe it is possible to reach this option with Python?

I have Googled but the most things I find is about reading excel files in openpyxl or xlwings. But did not find anything about using os.startfile() to open it as Read Only.
Can someone please guide me to the correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel will launch with a spreadsheet as read-only with the `/r` switch, e.g. `excel.exe /r "c:\My Folder\book1.xlsx"`

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Excel

Instead of passing the filename of the spreadsheet as the first argument to `os.startfile`, pass `Excel` to it instead, and then the right arguments to make it read-only followed by the filename enclosed in double quotes.

```py
os.startfile('Excel', arguments='/r "C:\spreadsheet file 1.xlsx"')
```

This is the same as entering `start Excel /r "C:\spreadsheet file 1.xlsx"` into the Windows Command Prompt.

Alternatively, you could manually get the path of Excel and run it with the right arguments using `winreg` and `subprocess.Popen`:

```py
# Step 1 - get the path of EXCEL.EXE (first method)
# This method queries the registry just once, which for me returns
# "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" "%1"
# But we only need the path without quotes 
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, r"Applications\EXCEL.EXE\shell\open\command")
excel_open_command = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "")[0]
winreg.CloseKey(key)

end = excel_open_command.lower().rindex(".exe") + len(".exe")
excel_exe_path = excel_open_command[:end].replace('"', "")

# Step 1 - get the path of EXCEL.EXE (second method)
# This method queries the registry twice, which for me returns the short name
# C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, r"Excel.Sheet\CLSID")
clsid = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "")[0]
winreg.CloseKey(key)

key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, rf"CLSID\{clsid}\LocalServer32")
excel_exe_path = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "")[0]
winreg.CloseKey(key)

# Step 2 - run Excel with the read-only switch followed by the spreadsheet filename
subprocess.Popen([excel_exe_path, "/r", r"C:\Spreadsheet.xlsx"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would love to use the single line option you start with. The Excel file we use the most have an extention of .xlsm instead of .xlsx. When I use the single line solution and use the correct path with .xlsm, it opens Excel and then I get a pop-up telling me it can't find the XLSX file and asks if the name is changed.

Do you have a clue why it wants to open it as xlsx file while I am telling it to open a xlsm file?

Comment: You need to enclose the filepath of the spreadsheet in double quotes, like so: `os.startfile('Excel', arguments='/r "C:\spreadsheet file 1.xlsx"')`. Without the double quotes (i.e. `os.startfile('Excel', arguments='/r C:\spreadsheet file 1.xlsx')`), Excel tries to open 3 files as read-only: `C:\spreadsheet`, `file`, and `1.xlsx`. If it doesn't have a file extension, it attempts to open them with these extensions `.xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb, .xltx, .xltm, .xla, .xls, .xlw, .xlc, .xlt, .xla, .xlm, .slk, .wks, .wk1, .wk3, .wq1, .csv, .txt, .dbf, .dif`, and then finally without any extension.

Comment: Also, if you're using a relative filepath instead of an absolute filepath, you might need to set the current working directory by using `os.startfile`'s `cwd` argument. For example, if the spreadsheet file is named `TheExcelFileWeUseTheMost.xlsm` and it's saved in the `C:\Stuff\Spreadsheets` directory, you could do this: `os.startfile('Excel', arguments='/r "TheExcelFileWeUseTheMost.xlsm"', cwd=r"C:\Stuff\Spreadsheets")`

Comment: This almost works for me. It now opens Excel and opens the file but not as read-only. I used this line: os.startfile('Excel', arguments='/r "Ceeltotaal-PythonTest.xlsm"', cwd=r"L:\CEEL\Werkmap")
Do you see any mistakes?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Open a Windows Command Prompt (press  Win + R and enter `cmd`) and enter `start Excel /r "L:\CEEL\Werkmap\Ceeltotaal-PythonTest.xlsm"`. Does that open it as read-only? If not, then your version of Excel mustn't support the read-only switch.

Comment: Yes, if I use the command prompt it does open it as read-only.

Comment: Try this in Python: `os.startfile('Excel', arguments=r'/r "L:\CEEL\Werkmap\Ceeltotaal-PythonTest.xlsm"')`

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much for helping me out. Can you also explain why this works so I also understand it?

Comment: You're welcome. What don't you understand, exactly? Why this didn't work `os.startfile('Excel', arguments='/r "Ceeltotaal-PythonTest.xlsm"', cwd=r"L:\CEEL\Werkmap")`, but this did `os.startfile('Excel', arguments=r'/r "L:\CEEL\Werkmap\Ceeltotaal-PythonTest.xlsm"')`?

Comment: Indeed. Why did adding the r do the trick? To me it looks like giving the same "order" twice. Like open the following path as read-only read-only.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I was unable to replicate your problem. I was able to open the spreadsheet up as read only-both ways. It's worth noting the first `r` here, the one before the opening single quote (`arguments=r'/r "L:\CEEL\Werkmap\Ceeltotaal-PythonTest.xlsm"'`) makes the following string a raw string. This prevents backslashes from being used as an escape character. Because Windows filepaths typically contain backslashes, it is good practice to always make filepath strings raw. The first 2 characters of the argument `/r` tells Excel to open the following files as read-only.